# How to force recursive renaming in Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The below code replaces the '&' character in a folder name with the word "and". How can I force recursion to go into subfolders?

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%f IN ("C:\T\*") DO (
    set "old_name=%%~nxf"
    SET "newfname=!old_name:&= and !"
    REN "%%~ff" "!newfname!" 
)
```

Comment: use `FOR /R /D` instead of only `/D`

Comment: To be more precise, the code is supposed to replace all ampersands with a five character string, not a three character one! _Take care with directory names containing **`!`** characters._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this task, from a `For` loop, I would choose to select only those directories which actually contain an ampersand.

Using the `Dir` command:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/AD-S-L "C:\T\*&*"') Do (Set "CN=%%~nxA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo Ren "%%A" "!CN:&= and !"
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

Or using a standard 'set' with `For` and utilising its directory and recursive options:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /D /R "C:\T" %%A In ("*&*") Do (Set "CN=%%~nxA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo Ren "%%A" "!CN:&= and !"
    EndLocal)
Pause
```

If you are happy with the output, you can remove `Echo`  from line `5` and optionally remove line `7`.

---

As an alternative, you could use a single `PowerShell` based line in your batch file:

```bat
PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\T' -Filter '*&*' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | Foreach { Rename-Item $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace('&', ' and ') -WhatIf }" & Pause
```

Or using aliases to shorten the line:

```bat
PowerShell -NoP "GCI 'C:\T' -Filt '*&*' -Rec|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|%%{RnI $_.FullName $_.Name.Replace('&',' and ') -Wh}"&Pause
```

In either of these cases, if you are happy with the output you can remove the `-WhatIf`|`-Wh` option and optionally the  `& Pause`|`&Pause`

---

*In all cases above I have chosen to replace `&` with  `and` , should you wish to replace those instances with the three character string, remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters on either side of `and` in your preferred solution.*

Comment: Thanks so much Compo, although your answer is the most thorough and really insightful but something wrong with the Ren line. It renders 'The syntax of the command is incorrect'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry @WalidMohammed, I have modified the two `For` loop examples to correct my mistake, please retry them.